# ¿Cómo implementar algoritmos de ordenamiento inverso para cualquier tipo de datos?

Tags: c, funciones, algoritmos

Estoy escribiendo un código en C donde tengo que implementar un algoritmo de tal forma que pueda ordenar (de forma inversa) un tipo de dato nuevo *racional*, por el método de inserción.

El nuevo tipo de dato *racional* se declara en un archivo de cabecera `racional.h`, así como (resumiendo) el prototipo de una función que convierte el *racional* a una representación de cadena, y el de otra que compara dos números racionales, la cual recibe *apuntadores a racionales* a comparar y regresa código de error en caso de recibir apuntador inválido: 1 si r>s, 0 si r==s, **-1 si r<s**.

```
typedef struct{
  int numerador;
  int denominador; 
  int entero; 
  int signo;
} racional;

int cmp_rac(const racional* r,const racional* s);

char* tostr_rac(char* sal, const racional* r);
```

Luego, esta función se implementa en un código `racional.c`.

Ahora, en un archivo `issort.c`, tengo lo siguiente: (resumiendo)

```
#include <string.h>
#include "racional.h"

void swap(void* x, void* y, int tam_dat){
  unsigned char aux[tam_dat];
  memcpy(aux, x, tam_dat);
  memcpy(x, y, tam_dat);
  memcpy(y, aux, tam_dat);
  return;
}

int main(){
  int i, j;
  char salida[1000];
  racional a[10];

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    j = i;
    while((j>=0) && (cmp_rac(&a[j], &a[j - 1])==-1)){
      swap(&a[j], &a[j - 1], sizeof(racional));
      j = j - 1;
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("\n\t %s", tostr_rac(salida, a+i));

  return 0;
}
```

Que, según algunos libros que consulté, así es como se ordenan los elementos de un arreglo por el método de inserción, que es lo que necesito.

El último `for` sirve para mostrar el arreglo ya ordenado. Dicho arreglo se define al principio del programa con otro ciclo y con unas funciones implementadas en `racional.c` (sí funciona, pero no lo muestro porque lo considero innecesario).

**Al momento de compilar `racional.c` e `issort.c` sí se me genera un archivo ejecutable; sin embargo, no me aparece absolutamente nada al intentar correrlo.**
Lo compilé antes de agregar las instrucciones de ordenamiento y sí me mostraba el arreglo ordenado, pero necesito que se muestre en orden inverso.

Agradecería mucho pudieran responderme esa pregunta o, en su defecto, indicarme si hay soluciones alternas. Incluso si me estoy equivocando en algo más y no me he percatado de ello.

Comment: Por favor, consulta lo que es un [mcve] y **proporciona uno**. Será muchísimo mas rápido ver **exactamente** que estás haciendo y el **error exacto** que estás obteniendo, que ir adivinado lo que es `aux`, `arr` y el resto de variables.

Comment: Podrias explicar como la respuesta que te dieron, que es correcta, no te funciono?

Comment: Utiliza alguna página como https://tio.run para mostrar el código que funciona al menos. Así le podemos hacer las modificaciones *que no imprimen nada* y descubrir el motivo.

Comment: puede haber un typo en `a+i` ?

Comment: `a+i` es lo mismo que `&a[i]`

Comment: `&a[j - 1]` cuando `j=0` es válido?

Answer (score 2):

En un arreglo los datos están almacenados de forma contigua. Por lo tanto, la distancia de un elemento a otro siempre va a ser un múltiplo del tamaño del tipo.

Supon que tienes un arreglo de enteros de 4 bytes que comienza en la dirección de memoria 10. El primer elemento está en la dirección 10, el segundo en la 14, el tercero en la 18 y así.

| Posición | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dirección | 10 | 14 | 18 | 22 | ... | 10 + 4n |

---

Aplicado a tu pregunta, supon que tienes un arreglo de enteros. Para `j`:

```
// arreglo[j]
uint64_t direccion = (uint64_t)arreglo;
direccion += j * sizeof(tipo);
int *puntero = (int*)direccion;
```

De forma similar, para `j + 1`:

```
// arreglo[j + 1]
uint64_t direccion = (uint64_t)arreglo;
direccion += (j + 1) * sizeof(tipo);
int *puntero = (int*)direccion;
```

Idealmente el tipo numérico tiene la misma precisión (y tamaño) que un puntero y no tiene signo ya que no existen direcciones negativas. Este ejemplo es con punteros de 64 bits.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, pero ya apliqué `direccion += (j + 1) * sizeof(tipo);` de forma similar y no me funcionó, ya que me sale un error de argumento de tipo inválido.

Comment: @Rixiha necesitamos más contexto entonces.